# Creating powershell script to get show on desktop enabled + rename with hostname

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm just a junior programmer, just started with programming and because my work requests me to create some handy powershell scripts I was wondering if you can help me with a particular one.

We have a lot of customers with a lot of servers. When they are newly installed I do check them and after that we do regular maintenance. Because each customer has several servers with different roles I want to have the "Computer" icon on my desktop.
I can do that by clicking start -> rightclick Computer -> Enable "Show on Desktop"
Furtheron I want to have this Computer icon renamed to the hostname (because the hostname tells me it's role in the domain)

Now my goal is to create a powershell script that creates this computer icon with hostname for all the server in the domain.

I've tried to search my way to the usual search engines and came up with this:

1) Locate with regedit `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` rename LocalizedString to LocalizedString.Old
2) Now switch to Regedit32 Create a new VALUE type Expand_SZ name it LocalizedString On XP and Windows 2000 with SP3 replace LocalizedString with `%Username% at %Computername%`

Which isn't suitable because we use W2K8R2SP1 servers.
After that I ended up with this script:

```
$ComputerName = "Localhost"
$Hive = "CurrentUser"
$Key = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel"
$MyComputer = "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
$UserFiles = "{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}"
$Kind = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]
$RegHive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]$hive
$RegKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($RegHive,$ComputerName)
$MyComputerValue = ($RegKey.OpenSubKey($Key)).GetValue($MyComputer)
$UserFilesValue = ($RegKey.OpenSubKey($Key)).GetValue($UserFiles)
if ($MyComputerValue -eq $null -or $MyComputerValue -eq 0)
{
    $Computer = $regKey.OpenSubKey($RootKey,$true)
    $Computer.SetValue($MyComputer, 1,$Kind::DWord)
}
if ($UserFilesValue -eq $null -or $UserFilesValue -eq 0)
{
    $User = $regKey.OpenSubKey($RootKey,$true)
    $User.SetValue($UserFiles, 1,$Kind::DWord)
}
```

This doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.

I know this registry key is used for the computer on desktop:

```
“{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}”=dword:00000000
```

Continued search...
So I found this:

```
To show the ‘My Computer’ icon on the desk"text-decoration:underline;">
[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
Name = {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
Type =REG_DWORD
Value = 0
To change the ‘My Computer’ icon to computer or user name:
[HKCR\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}]
Name = LocalizedString
Type = REG_EXPAND_SZ
Data value = %computername% or any combination you like – eg %username% %computername%
```

However the second part keeps giving me an error and even if i can get it to work, i want to run the script onces and all servers in domain should be having this update.

Thanks for helping out.

Best regards,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Changing `HKCR\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\LocalizedString` is still suitable on Server 2008 R2, but you need to take ownership of the key and grant administrators full access to it first.